# How to delete from a word to the end of the line

Tags: vim

I want to delete words beyond a particular word in all the lines in a file. For instance, if I have a file with the following lines:

```
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw1_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw2_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw3_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw6_something_Family
```

I want to delete the words from `inlaw1_something_Family, inlaw2_something_Family, inlaw3_something_Family ...`.

How can I do this automatically because I have many lines in a file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.
We'd like to see your attempt to solve the problem. Without that, it looks like you didn't try and want us to explain it, which is off-topic.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12642/4626. The [vi.se] site is for Vi questions, more so than Stack Overflow. Also, the Vim Wiki is invaluable: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Searching. I'd recommend spending time snooping all through it; There's a LOT of great information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all those line which have to be edited, then press `:` to go to command-mode. In command-mode type `:'<,'>s/inlaw.*//`

This will delete till end of line after searching for `inlaw.*`

Comment: Select all the lines? What if the file has thousands of lines with the target lines interspersed among them? While Vim supports visual selections, it's much easier to let Vim search and delete the text.

Comment: What you did was pretty much the same thing!

Comment: That's common, when there's a subset of the command that actually performs the action. The difference between the two seems tiny, but it boils down to how many times the selection will have to be made and then the action performed. While yours is workable with a file where every line contains the target, it becomes unwieldy on a file with thousands or hundreds of thousands of lines where only some contain the target.

Answer (score 0):

Enter: <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then `:1`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then `:%s/inlaw.\+//`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will put you in command mode, jump to the first line of the file, then search for every line matching, and *replace* from `inlaw...` to the end of the line with nothing, effectively deleting the text. `%s` is shorthand for "search every line in the file."

Read Vim's built-in help for `:h search` more information. There's no need to manually select lines, simply let Vim do the heavy lifting:

Before:

```
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw1_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw2_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw3_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw6_something_Family
```

After:

```
mom_dad_son_kid_
mom_dad_son_kid_
mom_dad_son_kid_
mom_dad_son_kid_
```

You can also do it in one command:

```
:1,:%s/inlaw.\+//
```

But I invariably do the jump before I even begin thinking about the search command. It's nice that Vim gives us that capability if we have the wherewithal to use it.

---

> What you did was pretty much the same thing!

Kinda, but how it works as part of a workflow is much different. Here's an example where this approach shines. In a file like this:

```
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw1_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_outlaw2_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_inlaw3_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_outlaw6_something_Family
```

A selection-based approach has to be done twice (or a more complex command issued), because there isn't a contiguous region containing multiple target-lines. This is an extremely common scenario, especially when processing data files, logs, etc. In a big file, like I was used to seeing, into the 100MB+ range, it's unworkable because it'd take hours to find, select, strip, rinse and repeat, whereas a single command does it throughout the file.

Instead, let Vim do the work of checking every line for the target using `%`, then perform the search/replace:

```
mom_dad_son_kid_
mom_dad_son_kid_outlaw2_something_Family
mom_dad_son_kid_
mom_dad_son_kid_outlaw6_something_Family
```

Of course, using Vim for multiple files is the wrong choice of a tool. It'd be trivial to do this with a `sed` command, or Perl, Python or Ruby.